# if we use struts2 with tiles, the total web part refresh or particular part refresh?

Tags: java, ajax, struts2, struts, tiles2

i have doubt on strus2 tiles, in my web application i am using tile base as follows.

```
<definition name="base" template="/pages/BaseLayout.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="" />
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/pages/header.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="menu" value="/pages/menu.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/pages/footer.jsp" />
</definition>
```

for every page this base layout is common, i am using this base as follows,

```
<definition name="/home.tiles" extends="base"> 
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Welcome page" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/pages/home.jsp" />
</definition>
```

and

```
<definition name="/deliveryHistory.tiles" extends="base">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Subscription List" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/pages/delivery_history.jsp" />
</definition>
```

my question is, when i load `"/deliveryHistory.tiles"` tiles using strus2 action, will the base tiles jsp pages reload(`header.jsp`, `menu.jsp`, and `footer.jsp`) or the particular `"delivery_history.jsp"` reloaded?

Comment: Why *wouldn't* they be? Also note that figuring this out for yourself is trivial: put a `System.out` or logging statement or JavaScript `alert` or *anything* in your JSP you can monitor, and the behavior can be determined in seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever the files included in that tiles configuration they will be reloaded so
in your case `header.jsp, menu.jsp and footer.jsp` will be reloaded